# getting deterministic values with java's securerandom

Tags: java, hash, salt

I am trying to get the same salt value everytime depending on the seed value. Here's the code I have

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(seed.getBytes());
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
sr.nextBytes(salt);
```

However, I keep getting different values everytime it is run. Am I doing something wrong is there something missing?

**Update:**

Ok I have tried the using random instead of secureRandom and to get bytes using long seed but I still get different values each time. However, when I change it to try to get nextInt I am able to get the same values.

```
Random rand = new Random(Long.parseLong(seed, 36));   
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
rand.nextBytes(salt);
```

Is there a work around correctly getting the same bytes?

Comment: You seem to be missing the "Secure" in "SecureRandom"...

Comment: @BrettOkken i understand that secureRandom offers better security but for my application it is important to produce the same hash result each time for the given input to the hash function. this is the reason why i am trying to get the same salt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional. SecureRandom tries to use entrophy in order to get true randomness, which by the way can be expensive. It will always return different values no matter what salt you start out with.

If you want deterministic values, use Random instead.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried using the random function but I still get different values everytime I run it. Here's the code I have: 
Random random = new Random (Long.parseLong(seed,36));
     byte[] salt = new byte[32];
     random.nextBytes(salt);
is there something I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps you have a problem with your seed? Replace the parseLong code with a hard-coded constant and run the program. You should get the same values every time. If that works you can investigate why the seed varies. I wrote a short program based on your code and new Random(1000L) and it consistently produces the same bytes!

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the parseLong code with new Random(1000L) as you did to but for some reason I am still getting different values. It looks exactly like this: 

Random random = new Random (1000L);
     byte[] salt = new byte[32];
     random.nextBytes(salt);

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the new code and not some old version? If so, what platform are you using? You could try with a different JDK. Sounds like a very unlikely bug, but when I run the code in your latest comment in a loop it produces the same bytes every time.

Comment: I am using eclipse and when I run it in a loop I get the same results for that loop as well. However, when I run the code over again I get the same value in the loop but different from the previous run.

Comment: The contract for the Random class guarantees that two instances with the same seed will generate the same numbers, so either you have a very odd bug or you are doing something wrong. How do you inspect the results? Do you print or look at the individual bytes, or do you just print the byte array object? The object will be different, but given the same seed and the same number of calls the random bytes should be identical every time. They are when I run the code in Eclipse.

Comment: Its been confusing for me as why it isn't generating the same values using the same seed. I print the bytes like this: System.out.print(salt + " ");

Comment: There you are then. You are invoking the toString method of the salt array, but unfortunately it does not print the byte values in the array. The output will vary as the objects are different. Try: `for (byte b : salt) { System.out.print(b + " "); }`